# Inner Join referencing columns not valid

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to do an inner join based on two columns and am having a problem  referencing the columns correctly.  I have used the following query which to the best of my knowledge is best pratice within postgresql.  The two tables I am attempting to do an inner join on are mk_kw & adwords_final, both columns that are to be joined on are named "Key"

Here is the query

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 adwords_final
INNER JOIN mk_kw ON "mk_kw.Key" = "adwords_final.Key";
```

Here is the result

```
ERROR:  column "mk_kw.Key" does not exist
LINE 5: INNER JOIN mk_kw ON "mk_kw.Key" = "adwords_final.Key";
                        ^
ERROR: column "mk_kw.Key" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 51
```

These columns certainly do exist within this context.  Is there a better way to  reference these columns?

Many Thanks.

Comment: you need to remove the quotations so instead of this `"mk_kw.key"`, write this `mk_kw.key`, also applied for `adwords_final.Key`.

Comment: ERROR:  column mk_kw.key does not exist
     LINE 5: INNER JOIN mk_kw ON mk_kw.key = adwords_final.key;
                            ^
     HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "mk_kw.Key".
     ********** Error **********

    ERROR: column mk_kw.key does not exist
    SQL state: 42703
    Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "mk_kw.Key".
    Character: 51

Comment: yes just remove the quotations... so its `mk_kw.Key` , after the dot you write the column name which is `Key` with a capital K.

Comment: Yes, I did that however I get the result that I posted up top there.

Answer (score 0):

The query should become:

```
 SELECT
 *
FROM
adwords_final
INNER JOIN mk_kw ON mk_kw.Key = adwords_final.Key;
```

Here is a sample of how to write inner joins:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
```

`Orders` and `Customers` are table names. `CustomerID`, `CustomerName`,`OrderID` are column names. All of them are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Haddad's solution will still give you an error because `key` is a reserved word. You need to individually wrap the column name part of the query in double quotes as below:

```sql
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  adwords_final 
INNER JOIN 
  mk_kw ON mk_kw."Key" = adwords_final."Key";
```

Edit: Updated to reflect comments below

Comment: "*column names are case sensitive*" - no they are not. They are only case sensitive when you use double quotes. Which means you used double quotes when you _created_ the table. But `key` will need to be quoted anyway as it is a reserved keyword

Comment: oh i guess my solution was correct but reasoning was wrong... thanks for clearing it up! So let's say i have a table called `todo` and want to join on a column called `userId`, i'll still need to double quote the userId because the 'I' is capitalised correct?

Comment: Correct: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS  But you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Ahhh I see! I'll look at the wiki link more carefully! The reason I have a `userId` is because I was using sequelize and it autocreated that foreign key on the `todo` table for me. I guess i should configure it to create the column name with underscore instead like `user_id`.